# Notepad++ adding words to autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++

I want to add some Keywords to Notepad, so when I start typing 
`he`
notepad will list
 `hello,hero`
 for example. I have found this tutorial 
[Notepad Tutorial(docs)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Editing_Configuration_Files#Autocompletion.2C_aka_API.2C_files)

But I don't want to add a whole method, I just want that word to be automatically completed by Notepad++.

Just for persons who are wondering why I need this: I will work a lot with .yml-files where I have lots of keywords and it costs a lot of time looking up all these words when I write a file.

Answer (score 0):

You found the correct documentation on how to add keywords, you don't have to add the whole method. You can use auto closing xml to simplify it

```
<NotepadPlus>
 <AutoComplete>        
    <KeyWord name="await" />
    <KeyWord name="base" />
    <KeyWord name="bool" />
    <KeyWord name="break" />
 </AutoComplete>
</NotepadPlus>
```

The name of the file has to be the same as the name of the language and needs to be in the `Program Files/NotePad++/plugins/APIs` folder. Keep in mind the list must be in alphabetical order or it will break without warning.